# Extract the text of string after a word in Bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

How can I extract the text after a word like `Modeline`.

I have a string,

```
mdline = 1600x900 59.95 Hz (CVT 1.44M9) hsync: 55.99 kHz; pclk: 118.25 MHz Modeline "1600x900_60.00" 118.25 1600 1696 1856 2112 900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
```

i.e a typical output of `cvt` command and I want to get the text after "Modeline".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

other variations

```
$ awk -F'Modeline ' '{print $2}' file
```

or

```
$ sed 's/.*Modeline //' file
```

Comment: awk -F'Modeline ' '{print $2}' file --> what if i want to get the string till a particular character(in my case ") is reached and omitting that character ?

Answer (score 5):

Using `bash` parameter-expansion,

```
string='mdline = 1600x900 59.95 Hz (CVT 1.44M9) hsync: 55.99 kHz; pclk: 118.25 MHz Modeline "1600x900_60.00" 118.25 1600 1696 1856 2112 900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync'

printf "%s\n" "${string#*Modeline }"
"1600x900_60.00" 118.25 1600 1696 1856 2112 900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
```

Answer (score 1):

With sed, using backreference:

```
$ sed 's/.*Modeline\(.*\)/\1/' <<< 'mdline = 1600x900 59.95 Hz (CVT 1.44M9) hsync: 55.99 kHz; pclk: 118.25 MHz Modeline "1600x900_60.00" 118.25 1600 1696 1856 2112 900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync'
 "1600x900_60.00" 118.25 1600 1696 1856 2112 900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
```